# Active link color is not changed when click on link

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am working in WordPress.I have fetched multiple data from the database and put them into an anchor tag. When I click on the link then its color doesn't change so I can not identify which link is active?

My CSS is:

```
.cd-popup-trigger:active {
    color: #000;
}
```

And my code is like this:

```
<a href="0#" class="cd-popup-trigger" id="cd-popup-trigger_<?php echo $trow->ID; ?>">
     <span class="tooltip-home-item" title="<?php echo  get_post_meta( $trow->ID, 'wpcf-short-description', true );?>">
          <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" alt="<?php echo $trow->post_title; ?>" width="20px" height="20px" />
          <label for="<?php echo $trow->post_name; ?>">
              <?php echo $trow->post_title; ?>
          </label>
     </span>
</a>
```

Moreover, I have used jQuery to display a popup box while clicking on it. And I have used tooltips on mouse over.
My website is [here](http://toleratedmerge.lancetek.com/) if you want to check it out. You can check it under food types on my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well right now you are adding the css to your active state, and its working. But if you want to add styling so even after clicking it remains there, then you will have to add a class through jQuery.

```
jQuery('.cd-popup-trigger').click(function(){
     jQuery('.cd-popup-trigger').removeClass('active');
     jQuery(this).addClass('active');

});
```

I haven't tested it, but what it should do is assign a class next to "cd-popup-trigger", and when you click on some other element, it will then remove the previous one and assign it to the new element.

Now you just have to style this in your css

```
.cd-popup-trigger.active label {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wordpress always add a class to its current selected item.

```
current-menu-item
```

So you can use it like

```
.current-menu-item {
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: I have added this class but it does not work.When i close my popup i could not recognize that which link was active in last?

Comment: @parth i could not found css you have added in your given link

Comment: When i use it my all listing display in black color.

Answer (score 0):

A CSS [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) is a keyword added to selectors that specifies a special state of **the element** to be selected. For example `:hover` will apply a style when the user hovers over the element specified by the selector.

Pseudo-classes, together with pseudo-elements, let you apply a style to an element not only in relation to the content of the document tree, but also in relation to external factors like the history of the navigator (`:visited`, for example), the status of its content (like `:checked` on some form elements), or the position of the mouse (like `:hover` which lets you know if the mouse is over an element or not).

The `:active` CSS pseudo-class matches when an element is being activated by the user. It allows the page to give a feedback that the activation has been detected by the browser. When interacting with a mouse, ***this is typically the time between the user presses the mouse button and releases it***. The `:active` pseudo-class is also ***typically matched when using the keyboard tab key***. It is frequently used on `<a>` and `<button>` HTML elements, but **may not** be limited to just those.

This style may be overridden by any other link-related pseudo-classes, that is `:link`, `:hover`, and `:visited`, appearing in subsequent rules.

In order to style the appropriate links, **you need to put the `:active` rule after all the other link-related rules**, as defined by the `LVHA-order`: `:link — :visited — :hover — :active`.

> Note: On systems with multi-button mice, CSS 3 specifies that the
>   `:active` pseudo-class must only apply to the **primary** button; on
>   right-handed mice, this is typically the **leftmost** button.